# Installing M2SSD into a typeE slot?

Tags: linux, ssd

I have manufactured an E-to-M M2 socket converter: it can be plugged into a keyE slot, and it can host a keyM device (NVME SSD).

Here is the schematic and layout I used: https://github.com/CRImier/MyKiCad/tree/master/Laptop%20mods/nvme_ae_to_m

Schematics:

[image]

Top layer:

[image]

Bottom layer:

[image]

(All credits go to @CRImier, thank you!)

I installed this into an SBC (NanoPi R5C) which software is designed for hosting Wifi cards on this M2 slot.

During booting, it can't detect the SSD in the M2 socket, due to some errors, which I'll show here (from dmesg).

It contains many trials on the PCIe to initialize the SSD, but it eventually fails.

Can I somehow disable the rfkill, or anything else, which prevents this SSD to run up?

Dmesg:

```
[    3.234151] rk-pcie 3c0000000.pcie: PCIe Link up, LTSSM is 0x130011
[    3.235663] pci 0002:20:00.0: Primary bus is hard wired to 0
[    3.235667] rk-pcie 3c0000000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    3.235680] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-0f]
[    3.235689] pci 0002:20:00.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 01-ff]), reconfiguring
[    3.235705] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [??? 0xf4000000-0xf40fffff flags 0x0]
[    3.235715] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0xfffff] (bus address [0xf4100000-0xf41fffff])
[    3.235723] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xf4200000-0xf5ffffff]
[    3.235732] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x300000000-0x33fffffff pref]
[    3.235769] pci 0000:00:00.0: [1d87:3566] type 01 class 0x060400
[    3.235796] pci 0000:00:00.0: reg 0x38: [mem 0x00000000-0x0000ffff pref]
[    3.235951] pci 0002:21:00.0: [10ec:8125] type 00 class 0x020000
[    3.235962] pci 0000:00:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    3.235969] pci 0000:00:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D3hot
[    3.236017] pci 0002:21:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0x0000-0x00ff]
[    3.236089] pci 0002:21:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0x00000000-0x0000ffff 64bit]
[    3.236125] rfkill_gpio m2-wlan-radio: m2-wlan-radio device registered.
[    3.236136] pci 0002:21:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0x00000000-0x00003fff 64bit]
[    3.236522] pci 0002:21:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    3.236530] pci 0002:21:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    3.237614] mmc2: SDHCI controller on fe310000.sdhci [fe310000.sdhci] using ADMA
[    3.237617] [BT_RFKILL]: Enter rfkill_rk_init
[    3.237626] [WLAN_RFKILL]: Enter rfkill_wlan_init
[    3.243220] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    3.244336] registered taskstats version 1
[    3.244359] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    3.244628] pstore: Using crash dump compression: deflate
[    3.245462] rga: rga2_irq, irq = 30, match scheduler
[    3.245823] rga: rga2 hardware loaded successfully, hw_version:3.2.63318.
[    3.245849] rga: rga2 probe successfully
[    3.246051] rga2_mmu: IOMMU binding successfully, default mapping core[0x4]
[    3.246271] rga: Module initialized. v1.2.20
[    3.247493] pci_bus 0000:01: busn_res: can not insert [bus 01-ff] under [bus 00-0f] (conflicts with (null) [bus 00-0f])
[    3.247618] pci 0000:01:00.0: [8086:2522] type 00 class 0x010802
[    3.247703] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00003fff 64bit]
[    3.247791] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0x00000000-0x0000ffff 64bit]
[    3.247846] pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
[    3.248288] pci 0000:01:00.0: 4.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 5.0 GT/s PCIe x1 link at 0000:00:00.0 (capable of 15.752 Gb/s with 8.0 GT/s PCIe x2 link)
[    3.255698] pci_bus 0002:21: busn_res: [bus 21-2f] end is updated to 21
[    3.255758] pci 0002:20:00.0: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x40000000]
[    3.255768] pci 0002:20:00.0: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x40000000]
[    3.255776] pci 0002:20:00.0: BAR 1: no space for [mem size 0x40000000]
[    3.255783] pci 0002:20:00.0: BAR 1: failed to assign [mem size 0x40000000]
[    3.255791] pci 0002:20:00.0: BAR 8: assigned [mem 0xf0200000-0xf02fffff]
[    3.255800] pci 0002:20:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xf0300000-0xf030ffff pref]
[    3.255808] pci 0002:20:00.0: BAR 7: assigned [io  0x100000-0x100fff]
[    3.255823] pci 0002:21:00.0: BAR 2: assigned [mem 0xf0200000-0xf020ffff 64bit]
[    3.255868] pci 0002:21:00.0: BAR 4: assigned [mem 0xf0210000-0xf0213fff 64bit]
[    3.255907] pci 0002:21:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [io  0x100000-0x1000ff]
[    3.255925] pci 0002:20:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 21]
[    3.255932] pci 0002:20:00.0:   bridge window [io  0x100000-0x100fff]
[    3.255940] pci 0002:20:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xf0200000-0xf02fffff]
[    3.255984] sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/devices/platform/3c0800000.pcie/pci0002:20/0002:20:00.0/config'
[    3.255995] CPU: 3 PID: 148 Comm: rk-pcie Not tainted 5.10.110 #178
[    3.256000] Hardware name: FriendlyElec NanoPi R5C (DT)
[    3.256005] Call trace:
[    3.256018]  dump_backtrace+0x0/0x1d4
[    3.256026]  show_stack+0x24/0x30
[    3.256035]  dump_stack_lvl+0xcc/0xf4
[    3.256042]  dump_stack+0x1c/0x5c
[    3.256050]  sysfs_warn_dup+0x70/0x90
[    3.256056]  sysfs_add_file_mode_ns+0x1ac/0x1b0
[    3.256062]  sysfs_create_bin_file+0x80/0xb0
[    3.256071]  pci_create_sysfs_dev_files+0x54/0x260
[    3.256078]  pci_bus_add_device+0x3c/0xc0
[    3.256084]  pci_bus_add_devices+0x48/0x94
[    3.256091]  pci_host_probe+0x4c/0xd0
[    3.256098]  dw_pcie_host_init+0x1cc/0x410
[    3.256105]  rk_pcie_really_probe+0xcd4/0x10a0
[    3.256114]  kthread+0x130/0x134
[    3.256121]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x3c
[    3.258409] pcieport 0002:20:00.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 115
[    3.258555] sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/devices/platform/3c0800000.pcie/pci0002:20/0002:20:00.0/0002:21:00.0/config'
[    3.258568] CPU: 3 PID: 148 Comm: rk-pcie Not tainted 5.10.110 #178
[    3.258574] Hardware name: FriendlyElec NanoPi R5C (DT)
[    3.258579] Call trace:
[    3.258592]  dump_backtrace+0x0/0x1d4
[    3.258600]  show_stack+0x24/0x30
[    3.258612]  dump_stack_lvl+0xcc/0xf4
[    3.258619]  dump_stack+0x1c/0x5c
[    3.258627]  sysfs_warn_dup+0x70/0x90
[    3.258633]  sysfs_add_file_mode_ns+0x1ac/0x1b0
[    3.258639]  sysfs_create_bin_file+0x80/0xb0
[    3.258648]  pci_create_sysfs_dev_files+0x54/0x260
[    3.258656]  pci_bus_add_device+0x3c/0xc0
[    3.258662]  pci_bus_add_devices+0x48/0x94
[    3.258667]  pci_bus_add_devices+0x74/0x94
[    3.258674]  pci_host_probe+0x4c/0xd0
[    3.258681]  dw_pcie_host_init+0x1cc/0x410
[    3.258688]  rk_pcie_really_probe+0xcd4/0x10a0
[    3.258697]  kthread+0x130/0x134
[    3.258704]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x3c
[    3.258750] rk-pcie 3c0800000.pcie: missing "busno" property
[    3.269256] pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 8: assigned [mem 0xf4200000-0xf42fffff]
[    3.269284] pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xf4300000-0xf430ffff pref]
[    3.269300] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 4: assigned [mem 0xf4200000-0xf420ffff 64bit]
[    3.269342] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xf4210000-0xf4213fff 64bit]
[    3.269380] pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01-ff]
[    3.269389] pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xf4200000-0xf42fffff]
[    3.269430] sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/devices/platform/3c0000000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/config'
[    3.269440] CPU: 0 PID: 146 Comm: rk-pcie Not tainted 5.10.110 #178
[    3.269445] Hardware name: FriendlyElec NanoPi R5C (DT)
[    3.269450] Call trace:
[    3.269462]  dump_backtrace+0x0/0x1d4
[    3.269469]  show_stack+0x24/0x30
[    3.269478]  dump_stack_lvl+0xcc/0xf4
[    3.269484]  dump_stack+0x1c/0x5c
[    3.269492]  sysfs_warn_dup+0x70/0x90
[    3.269499]  sysfs_add_file_mode_ns+0x1ac/0x1b0
[    3.269505]  sysfs_create_bin_file+0x80/0xb0
[    3.269514]  pci_create_sysfs_dev_files+0x54/0x260
[    3.269521]  pci_bus_add_device+0x3c/0xc0
[    3.269526]  pci_bus_add_devices+0x48/0x94
[    3.269532]  pci_host_probe+0x4c/0xd0
[    3.269539]  dw_pcie_host_init+0x1cc/0x410
[    3.269545]  rk_pcie_really_probe+0xcd4/0x10a0
[    3.269553]  kthread+0x130/0x134
[    3.269560]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x3c
[    3.271570] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 117
[    3.271900] friendlyelec-board board: Serial     : c770b7233d8fb7c0
[    3.272129] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:01:00.0
[    3.272257] nvme 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.272763] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: Adding to iommu group 5
[    3.272964] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: probing start
[    3.273182] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: Looking up venc-supply from device tree
[    3.273339] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: Failed to get leakage
[    3.273384] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: pvtm = 88780, from nvmem
[    3.273395] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: pvtm-volt-sel=1
[    3.273555] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: avs=0
[    3.273653] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: failed to find power_model node
[    3.273661] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: failed to initialize power model
[    3.273668] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: failed to get dynamic-coefficient
[    3.273987] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: probing finish
[    3.274309] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: Adding to iommu group 6
[    3.274569] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: rkvdec, probing start
[    3.274598] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: link mode task capacity 16
[    3.274846] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: shared_niu_a is not found!
[    3.274855] rkvdec2_init:1006: No niu aclk reset resource define
[    3.274862] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: shared_niu_h is not found!
[    3.274868] rkvdec2_init:1009: No niu hclk reset resource define
[    3.274891] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: Looking up vdec-supply from device tree
[    3.275115] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: leakage=55
[    3.275127] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: leakage-volt-sel=0
[    3.275161] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: pvtm = 88780, from nvmem
[    3.275171] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: pvtm-volt-sel=1
[    3.275338] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: avs=0
[    3.275438] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: failed to find power_model node
[    3.275446] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: failed to initialize power model
[    3.275453] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: failed to get dynamic-coefficient
[    3.275570] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: sram_start 0x00000000fdcc0000
[    3.275579] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: rcb_iova 0x0000000010000000
[    3.275584] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: sram_size 45056
[    3.275590] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: rcb_size 65536
[    3.275596] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: min_width 512
[    3.275643] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: link mode probe finish
[    3.275696] mpp_rkvdec2 fdf80200.rkvdec: probing finish
[    3.276179] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: Looking up pmuio1-supply from device tree
[    3.276192] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: Looking up pmuio1-supply property in node /syscon@fdc20000/io-domains failed
[    3.276222] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: Looking up pmuio2-supply from device tree
[    3.276368] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: pmuio2(3300000 uV) supplied by vcc3v3_pmu
[    3.276378] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: Looking up vccio1-supply from device tree
[    3.276424] rockchip-pm-domain fdd90000.power-management:power-controller: Looking up gpu-supply from device tree
[    3.276442] rockchip-pm-domain fdd90000.power-management:power-controller: Looking up gpu-supply property in node /power-management@fdd90000/power-controller failed
[    3.276494] mali fde60000.gpu: Kernel DDK version g13p0-01eac0
[    3.276508] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: vccio1(3300000 uV) supplied by vccio_acodec
[    3.276517] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: Looking up vccio2-supply from device tree
[    3.276526] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: Looking up vccio2-supply property in node /syscon@fdc20000/io-domains failed
[    3.276538] mali fde60000.gpu: Looking up mali-supply from device tree
[    3.276541] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: Looking up vccio3-supply from device tree
[    3.276661] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: vccio3(3300000 uV) supplied by vccio_sd
[    3.276670] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: Looking up vccio4-supply from device tree
[    3.276693] mali fde60000.gpu: Looking up mem-supply from device tree
[    3.276704] mali fde60000.gpu: Looking up mem-supply property in node /gpu@fde60000 failed
[    3.276762] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: vccio4(1800000 uV) supplied by vcc_1v8
[    3.276771] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: Looking up vccio5-supply from device tree
[    3.276774] mali fde60000.gpu: Looking up mali-supply from device tree
[    3.276795] vdd_gpu: could not add device link fde60000.gpu: -EEXIST
[    3.276799] vdd_gpu: Failed to create debugfs directory
[    3.276863] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: vccio5(3300000 uV) supplied by vcc_3v3
[    3.276872] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: Looking up vccio6-supply from device tree
[    3.276891] mali fde60000.gpu: leakage=8
[    3.276917] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: vccio6(1800000 uV) supplied by vcc_1v8
[    3.276926] mali fde60000.gpu: pvtm = 88780, from nvmem
[    3.276929] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: Looking up vccio7-supply from device tree
[    3.276941] mali fde60000.gpu: pvtm-volt-sel=1
[    3.276991] rockchip-iodomain fdc20000.syscon:io-domains: vccio7(3300000 uV) supplied by vcc_3v3
[    3.277534] mali fde60000.gpu: avs=0
[    3.277558] W : [File] : drivers/gpu/arm/bifrost/platform/rk/mali_kbase_config_rk.c; [Line] : 136; [Func] : kbase_platform_rk_init(); power-off-delay-ms not available.
[    3.277901] mali fde60000.gpu: GPU identified as 0x2 arch 7.4.0 r1p0 status 0
[    3.278029] mali fde60000.gpu: No priority control manager is configured
[    3.278040] mali fde60000.gpu: No memory group manager is configured
[    3.278958] mali fde60000.gpu: Couldn't find power_model DT node matching 'arm,mali-simple-power-model'
[    3.278979] mali fde60000.gpu: Error -22, no DT entry: mali-simple-power-model.static-coefficient = 1*[0]
[    3.279219] mali fde60000.gpu: Error -22, no DT entry: mali-simple-power-model.dynamic-coefficient = 1*[0]
[    3.279446] mali fde60000.gpu: Error -22, no DT entry: mali-simple-power-model.ts = 4*[0]
[    3.279637] mali fde60000.gpu: Error -22, no DT entry: mali-simple-power-model.thermal-zone = ''
[    3.281603] mali fde60000.gpu: Using configured power model mali-g52_r1-power-model, and fallback mali-simple-power-model
[    3.281797] mali fde60000.gpu: l=-2147483648 h=2147483647 hyst=0 l_limit=0 h_limit=0 h_table=0
[    3.283005] mali fde60000.gpu: Probed as mali0
[    3.283965] mmc2: new HS200 MMC card at address 0001
[    3.284527] mmcblk2: mmc2:0001 A3A551 28.9 GiB 
[    3.284766] mmcblk2boot0: mmc2:0001 A3A551 partition 1 4.00 MiB
[    3.284845] rockchip-pm-domain fdd90000.power-management:power-controller: Looking up vi-supply from device tree
[    3.284894] rockchip-pm-domain fdd90000.power-management:power-controller: Looking up vi-supply property in node /power-management@fdd90000/power-controller failed
[    3.285032] mmcblk2boot1: mmc2:0001 A3A551 partition 2 4.00 MiB
[    3.285143] mmcblk2rpmb: mmc2:0001 A3A551 partition 3 16.0 MiB, chardev (237:0)
[    3.285869] input: gpio-keys as /devices/platform/gpio-keys/input/input1
[    3.287134] RKNPU fde40000.npu: Adding to iommu group 0
[    3.287621] RKNPU fde40000.npu: RKNPU: rknpu iommu is enabled, using iommu mode
[    3.287678] RKNPU fde40000.npu: Looking up rknpu-supply from device tree
[    3.287849] RKNPU fde40000.npu: Looking up mem-supply from device tree
[    3.287863] RKNPU fde40000.npu: Looking up mem-supply property in node /npu@fde40000 failed
[    3.287902] RKNPU fde40000.npu: can't request region for resource [mem 0xfde40000-0xfde4ffff]
[    3.288338] [drm] Initialized rknpu 0.8.2 20220829 for fde40000.npu on minor 1
[    3.288555] RKNPU fde40000.npu: Looking up rknpu-supply from device tree
[    3.288587] vdd_npu: could not add device link fde40000.npu: -EEXIST
[    3.288590] vdd_npu: Failed to create debugfs directory
[    3.288733] RKNPU fde40000.npu: leakage=4
[    3.288788] RKNPU fde40000.npu: pvtm = 88780, from nvmem
[    3.288802] RKNPU fde40000.npu: pvtm-volt-sel=1
[    3.289395] RKNPU fde40000.npu: avs=0
[    3.289513] nvme nvme0: 4/0/0 default/read/poll queues
[    3.289597] RKNPU fde40000.npu: l=0 h=2147483647 hyst=5000 l_limit=0 h_limit=0 h_table=0
[    3.289990] RKNPU fde40000.npu: failed to find power_model node
[    3.290002] RKNPU fde40000.npu: RKNPU: failed to initialize power model
[    3.290009] RKNPU fde40000.npu: RKNPU: failed to get dynamic-coefficient
[    3.291567]  mmcblk2: p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9
[    3.292161] rockchip-pm rockchip-suspend: not set pwm-regulator-config
[    3.294085] ALSA device list:
[    3.294106]   #0: rockchip,hdmi
[    3.294112]   #1: ROCKCHIP,SPDIF
[    3.301875] Freeing unused kernel memory: 6784K
[    3.327419] rk-pcie 3c0400000.pcie: PCIe Link up, LTSSM is 0x130011
[    3.327578] rk-pcie 3c0400000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0001:10
[    3.327592] pci_bus 0001:10: root bus resource [bus 10-1f]
[    3.327600] pci_bus 0001:10: root bus resource [??? 0xf2000000-0xf20fffff flags 0x0]
[    3.327609] pci_bus 0001:10: root bus resource [io  0x200000-0x2fffff] (bus address [0xf2100000-0xf21fffff])
[    3.327615] pci_bus 0001:10: root bus resource [mem 0xf2200000-0xf3ffffff]
[    3.327622] pci_bus 0001:10: root bus resource [mem 0x340000000-0x37fffffff pref]
[    3.327655] pci 0001:10:00.0: [1d87:3566] type 01 class 0x060400
[    3.327678] pci 0001:10:00.0: reg 0x38: [mem 0x00000000-0x0000ffff pref]
[    3.327735] pci 0001:10:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    3.327742] pci 0001:10:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D3hot
[    3.334199] Run /init as init process
[    3.334224]   with arguments:
[    3.334227]     /init
[    3.334230]   with environment:
[    3.334232]     HOME=/
[    3.334234]     TERM=linux
[    3.334236]     storagemedia=emmc
[    3.334238]     data=/dev/mmcblk2p9
[    3.334240]     cgroup_enable=memory
[    3.334242]     cgroup_memory=1
[    3.334294] pci 0001:10:00.0: Primary bus is hard wired to 0
[    3.334309] pci 0001:10:00.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 01-ff]), reconfiguring
[    3.334563] pci 0001:11:00.0: [10ec:8125] type 00 class 0x020000
[    3.334631] pci 0001:11:00.0: reg 0x10: [io  0x0000-0x00ff]
[    3.334710] pci 0001:11:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0x00000000-0x0000ffff 64bit]
[    3.334765] pci 0001:11:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0x00000000-0x00003fff 64bit]
[    3.335157] pci 0001:11:00.0: supports D1 D2
[    3.335165] pci 0001:11:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[    3.352774] pci_bus 0001:11: busn_res: [bus 11-1f] end is updated to 11
[    3.352905] pci 0001:10:00.0: BAR 8: assigned [mem 0xf2200000-0xf22fffff]
[    3.352921] pci 0001:10:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xf2300000-0xf230ffff pref]
[    3.352930] pci 0001:10:00.0: BAR 7: assigned [io  0x200000-0x200fff]
[    3.352941] pci 0001:11:00.0: BAR 2: assigned [mem 0xf2200000-0xf220ffff 64bit]
[    3.352985] pci 0001:11:00.0: BAR 4: assigned [mem 0xf2210000-0xf2213fff 64bit]
[    3.353022] pci 0001:11:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [io  0x200000-0x2000ff]
[    3.353039] pci 0001:10:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 11]
[    3.353046] pci 0001:10:00.0:   bridge window [io  0x200000-0x200fff]
[    3.353054] pci 0001:10:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xf2200000-0xf22fffff]
[    3.355217] pcieport 0001:10:00.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 133
[    3.364353] vendor storage:20190527 ret = 0
```

Especially, these below lines (copied from the log above) are interesting (they are not present, when the SSD is not inserted):

```
rk-pcie 3c0000000.pcie: PCIe Link up, LTSSM is 0x130011
rk-pcie 3c0000000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-0f]
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [??? 0xf4000000-0xf40fffff flags 0x0]
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0xfffff] (bus address [0xf4100000-0xf41fffff])
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xf4200000-0xf5ffffff]
pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x300000000-0x33fffffff pref]
pci 0000:00:00.0: [1d87:3566] type 01 class 0x060400
pci 0000:00:00.0: reg 0x38: [mem 0x00000000-0x0000ffff pref]
pci 0000:00:00.0: supports D1 D2
pci 0000:00:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D3hot
pci_bus 0000:01: busn_res: can not insert [bus 01-ff] under [bus 00-0f] (conflicts with (null) [bus 00-0f])
pci 0000:01:00.0: [8086:2522] type 00 class 0x010802
pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00003fff 64bit]
pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x20: [mem 0x00000000-0x0000ffff 64bit]
pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
pci 0000:01:00.0: 4.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 5.0 GT/s PCIe x1 link at 0000:00:00.0 (capable of 15.752 Gb/s with 8.0 GT/s PCIe x2 link)
sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/devices/platform/3c0800000.pcie/pci0002:20/0002:20:00.0/config'
sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/devices/platform/3c0800000.pcie/pci0002:20/0002:20:00.0/0002:21:00.0/config'
 pci_bus_add_devices+0x74/0x94
pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 8: assigned [mem 0xf4200000-0xf42fffff]
pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 6: assigned [mem 0xf4300000-0xf430ffff pref]
pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 4: assigned [mem 0xf4200000-0xf420ffff 64bit]
pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xf4210000-0xf4213fff 64bit]
pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01-ff]
pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xf4200000-0xf42fffff]
sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/devices/platform/3c0000000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/config'
CPU: 0 PID: 146 Comm: rk-pcie Not tainted 5.10.110 #178
pcieport 0000:00:00.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 117
nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:01:00.0
nvme 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
nvme nvme0: 4/0/0 default/read/poll queues
pcieport 0001:10:00.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 133
```

What can I do to make this system support this operation?

Comment: this doesn't look like rfkill or any other userland software is to blame – there's a bus address clash.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how could I solve this? (Pls see my update for reference design of the converter I used)